# Distribute values

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I would like to distribute for each unique value in col1 an unique value of col2 in an ascendant order.

### DATA

This will be always n^n, where n is the number of values assignable to an unique value of col1

```
 -------------
| col1 | col2 |
|------|------|
|    a |     1|
|    a |     2|
|    a |     3|
|    b |     1|
|    b |     2|
|    b |     3|
|    c |     1|
|    c |     2|
|    c |     3|
---------------
```

On the first loop, I want to distribute 'a' to the first available value which is '1'. As 'a' has a value, {a: 2} and {a: 3} are removed. And as '1' is assigned, {b: 1} and {c: 1} are removed.

### So the expected result at the end

```
 -------------
| col1 | col2 |
|------|------|
|    a |     1|
|    b |     2|
|    c |     3|
---------------
```

### My tests

The first query could be `SELECT DISTINCT ON (col1) * FROM ... ORDER BY col1 ASC`, but the result is:

```
 -------------
| col1 | col2 |
|------|------|
|    a |     1|
|    b |     1|
|    c |     1|
---------------
```

So I would like to execute something like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col1) AND DISTINCT ON (col2) *
FROM ... 
ORDER BY col1, col2 ASC
```

With the first `DISTINCT` execution:

```
 -------------
| col1 | col2 |
|------|------|
|    a |     1|
|    b |     1|
|    b |     2|
|    b |     3|
|    c |     1|
|    c |     2|
|    c |     3|
---------------
```

And the second one:

```
 -------------
| col1 | col2 |
|------|------|
|    a |     1|
|    b |     2|
|    b |     3|
|    c |     2|
|    c |     3|
---------------
```

Comment: You see, computers can't read your mind; you have to explicitly tell them what to do. If you "don't really know how to explain what [you] want", there is absolutely no way anyone could direct a computer to deliver the result. So please, start with explaining how you have arrived at the expected result.

Comment: Hi and welcome to dba.se! [Here's](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4e7df20fcdb7e82880f77c7dc3e654c8) an answer. It's useless without a context - you'll have to explain what you are trying to do in the question itself! Also, when you are asking questions, please provide your DDL (`CREATE TABLE...`) and DML (`INSERT INTO...`) in the body of the question and, ideally, also on a fiddle site like the one I've linked to! Take a look at my profile - there are a few articles on how to ask questions there which might help you! Put a comment with `@` & Vérace (no space) below this.

Comment: @mustaccio that was complicated to explain clearly what I want, but I think it's much better now

Comment: Please declare your version of Postgres (`SELECT version();`). And tell us more about possible input. Your sample rows make it seem like every distinct value in `col1` is combined with the same set of values in `col2`. Is that so? What to do if there is no distinct value in `col2` left for the next value in `col1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sample data makes it seem like this could be the solution:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS col1_rnk
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2) AS col2_rn
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
WHERE  col1_rnk = col2_rn
ORDER  BY col1, col2;  -- optional
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5e589ed779ee201d0ee2b8b7d696e4a5)*

This is really a guess, though, as your problem is barely defined.
Among other things this assumes that every distinct value in `col1` is combined with the same set of values in `col2`.

Comment: What's the difference between your solution and the one [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/313187/distribute-values#comment610146_313187), except that yours requires a subquery whereas mine doesn't? I agree though that we flying blind given the paucity of information from the OP!

Comment: @Vérace-СлаваУкраїні: Your query only uses `col1`. Quite different. *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d1c1110d423f1f95cd23b0550ab6896c)* Anyway, the OP needs to define the problem more closely.

Comment: Yes, but my solution works in [this condition](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=962bf5d22f50f7e2a063c17e265d2145) - anyway, all of this is a pointless exercise without access to a crystal ball! Thanks for the clarification.